# Compare rows and get percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I found it hard to find a fitting title. For simplicity let's say I have the following table:

```
cook_id cook_rating
1       2
1       1
1       3
1       4
1       2
1       2
1       1
1       3
1       5
1       4
2       5
2       2
```

Now I would like to get an output of 'good' cooks. A good cook is someone who has a rating of at least 70% of 1, 2 or 3, but not 4 or 5.

So in my example table, the cook with id 1 has a total of 10 ratings, 7 of which have type 1, 2 and 3. Only three have type 4 or 5. Therefore the cook with id 1 would be a 'good' cook, and the output should be the cook's id with the number of good ratings.

```
cook_id cook_rating
1       7
```

The cook with id 2, however, doesn't satisfy my condition, therefore should not be listed at all.

```
select cook_id, count(cook_rating) - sum(case when cook_rating = 4 OR cook_rating = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as numberOfGoodRatings from cook
where cook_rating in (1,2,3,4,5)
group by cook_id
order by numberOfGoodRatings desc
```

However, this doesn't take into account the fact that there might be more 4 or 5 than good ratings, resulting in negative outputs. Plus, the requirement of at least 70% is not included.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be interested by the solution of [this article](http://evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html).

Comment: Nice article, but too complex for my needs. In my case I only want to sort for number of useful ratings, if the person had more then 70% of good ratings. So someone with 10 good ratings and 0 bad rating is still 'worth less' than someone who had 1000 good ratings, but 300 negative ones, even if this is not a good way of rating someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this with a comparison in your HAVING clause. If you must have just the two columns in the result set, this can be wrapped as a sub-select `select cook_id, positive_ratings FROM (...)`

```
SELECT 
  cook_id, 
  count(cook_rating < 4 OR cook_rating IS NULL) as positive_ratings, 
  count(*) as total_ratings
FROM cook
GROUP BY cook_id
HAVING (positive_ratings / total_ratings) >= 0.70
ORDER BY positive_ratings DESC
```

**Edit** Note that count(cook_rating < 4) is intended to only count rows where the rating is less than 4. The MySQL documentation says that count will only count non-null rows. I haven't tested this to see if it equates FALSE with NULL but I would be surprised it it doesn't. Worst case scenario we would need to wrap that in an `IF(cook_rating < 4, 1,NULL)`.

Comment: I was just going to ask, what happens if cook_rating is null. I'll try this query, when I get home. I'll probably use `coalesce`, instead of `if`.

Comment: If the rating is NULL, it will not be involved in the results at all, since it will not be matched by either the positive_ratings count() or the total_ratings count(). You can ensure this by adding `WHERE cook_rating IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @TerryUhlang what do you WANT to do if rating is null?

Comment: Forgot to mention. No rating is equal to positiv rating.

Comment: Ah... then we need to change the first COUNT a little to accommodate that. COUNT(cook_rating < 4 OR cook_rating IS NULL)

Comment: also modified the total_ratings count() to match those as well (* matches NULLs per the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change a little your schema to make this kind of queries trivial.

Suppose you add 5 columns to your cook table, to simply count the number of each ratings :

```
nb_ratings_1 nb_ratings_2 nb_ratings_3 nb_ratings_4 nb_ratings_5
```

Updating such a table when a new rating is entered in DB is trivial, just as would be recomputing those numbers if having redundancy makes you nervous. And it makes all filterings and sortings fast and easy.

Comment: This is not a normalized schema! I would assume the tables in the question are "rating events", which each correspond to a user-rating of a cook, in which case it is very valuable to have each event as a row. Additionally, what happens when you modify the system to support ratings between 1 and 10? Change your schema?

Comment: Of course this wouldn't prevent the saving of each rating individually (that's why I mentioned redundancy). And yes it means you add columns if you change the problem. A database must be practical and fast give the useful results you need. The goal of this propagation structure is to allow most kind of rating/sorting to be fast computed.