# Joining tables, if percentage is above certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is similar to this one:
[Compare rows and get percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384723/compare-rows-and-get-percentage)

However, little different. I adapted my question to the other post.

I got 2 tables.

First table:

```
user_id | post_id
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         12
2         15
```

And second table:

```
post_id | rating
1         1
1         2
1         3 
2         1
2         5
3         1
3         1
3         4
12        4
15        1
```

So now I would like to count the rating for each post, in the second table.
If the rating has more than, lets say, 50% positive ratings than I want to get the post_id and going it to the post_id from table one and add 1 to the user_id.

At the end it would return the user_id with the number of positive posts.

The result for above table would be:

```
user_id | helpfulPosts
1         2
2         1
```

The post with post_id 1 and 3 have positive rating, because more than 50% have ratings of 1-3. The post with id = 2 is not positive, because the rating is exactly 50%.

How would I achieve this?

For clarification:
It's a mysql rdbm and a positive post, is one where the number of rating_ids with 1, 2 and 3 are more than half of the overall rating. Basically the same thing, from the other thread I posted above.

Forgot one thing:
There is also the possibility that one post_id in posts table exist, but there is no rating for it, in the ratings_table. Those posts count as helpful as well.
The case with `null` as rating, was a misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: You should probably explain what you mean by "positive rating". I think I understand now, but it wasn't clear when I first read your question.

Comment: Just curious, what type of SQL DBMS?

Comment: I revised my solution to account for posts not having any ratings, and include those posts as "helpful posts" along with those posts with positive ratings of more than 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    COUNT(1) AS helpfulPosts
FROM
    posts a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            post_id, 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN rating IN (1,2,3) OR rating IS NULL THEN 1 END) / COUNT(1) AS percent_positive
        FROM ratings
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
WHERE
    b.post_id IS NULL OR
    b.percent_positive > 0.5
GROUP BY
    a.user_id
```

---

[SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/164ee/1/0)

^ Notice I added posts to user_id `1` that has no ratings, and those are counted towards the user's `helpfulPosts`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to first figure out which posts are helpful.  Using your logic, this is just calculating the average rating, when a rating is present.

```
select u.user_id, count(*) as HelpfulPosts
from UserPosts u join
     (select post_id,
             sum(case when rating in (1, 2, 3) then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(rating) as HelpfulRating 
      from PostRating pr
      group by post_id
     ) r
     on r.post_id = u.post_id
where r.HelpfulRating > 0.5
group by user_id
```

The next step is to join this back to the user posts table, grouping by user id, to count the number of helpful posts.

By the way, I don't see how "3" is considered helpful.  Do you mean 15 instead?  The above query ignores NULL rating.  If NULL should be considered as helpful, then use:

```
             sum(case when coalesce(rating, 1) in (1, 2, 3) then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / count(*) as HelpfulRating
```

instead of the version in the query.

Comment: Yes, post 3 is helpful, because it got no rating (null), one rating with one and one with a 4. Therefore, the overall rating is 66,667% (null is treated like 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: You'll want to change `count(rating)` to `count(*)` or else it will not count the `NULL` rating towards the total number of ratings.

Comment: I am sorry that was actually my fault. Null shouldn't be counted into the rating itself. There is no null as rating. Please see the last paragraph in my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

```
select up.user_id, count(up.post_id) as helpfulPosts
from userposts as up
where up.post_id in (
    select pr.post_id
    from postratings as pr
    group by pr.post_id
    having
        sum(case when pr.rating between 4 and 5 then 0 else 1 end) > 
        sum(case when pr.rating between 4 and 5 then 1 else 0 end)
)
group by up.user_id
```

Comment: This avoids the whole (minor) problem with integer division. I've run into a lot of people who forget about that.

Comment: I revised because of your note about how null contributes to a positive review. You have a variety of ways to express the positive rating condition if you find that one reads more clearly than another.